# mysqli filter by parameter with show all option

Tags: sql, mysqli, show, records

What is the best way to modify this query to show all records if parameter matches for showall, is it normal practise to use:

```
if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == 'showall')   ... else ? 

SELECT id, heading, category FROM table WHERE category = %s ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way would probaply be this:

```
if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == 'showall'){
execute : SELECT id, heading, category FROM table ORDER BY `date` DESC

} else if(isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != 'showall') {

execute : SELECT id, heading, category FROM table WHERE category = %s ORDER BY `date` DESC

}
```